# How can we disable Purge Protection in Key vault?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I have enabled the purge protection and soft delete on key vault, now i want to disable it . Is there any way to disable purge protection ?

I have created the key vault through terraform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to disable Purge Protection

> It is as designed, purge protection is irreversible. Otherwise hacker
> would be able to delete your key vault without option to recover.

Ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/8075

Also make note that soft delete will be enabled by default starting next year

> Breaking Change: The ability to opt out of soft-delete will be
> deprecated by the end of the year and soft-delete protection will
> automatically be turned on for all key vaults. Azure Key Vault users
> and administrators should enable soft-delete on their key vaults
> immediately.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-change

Comment: So, how do you get rid of it then when you're testing these security changes? Do I really have to pick a new name each and every time I do this?

Comment: Lifecicle:

1. Create the keyvault making sure purge protection is NOT enabled

2.. Remove the key vault

3. Purge it:

_KV=my_unique_keyvault_name && \
date && time az keyvault purge --name $_KV

Answer (score 1):

If you have purge protection enabled, you can add random suffix to keyvault name
for example. kv-prod-name{date time/releaseId}. Every time your pipeline runs it will create new key vault. After the retention period the deleted key vault will purge automatically from the deleted key vaults.